# How to set the popup keyboard to only show certain keys?

Tags: iphone, xcode

How do you set the popup keyboard to only show certain keys when you type into a textfield? I know there are default keyboards but none seems suitable.  Is there an alternative input option? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS 3.2, you can change the keyboard :

cf.
[Official documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-DontLinkElementID_3)

> Discussion
>
> The value of this property is nil.
>   Responder objects that require a
>   custom view to gather input from the
>   user should redeclare this property as
>   readwrite and use it to manage their
>   custom input view. When the receiver
>   subsequently becomes the first
>   responder, the responder
>   infrastructure presents the specified
>   input view automatically. Similarly,
>   when the view resigns its first
>   responder status, the responder
>   infrastructure automatically dismisses
>   the specified view.
>
> This property is typically used to
>   replace the system-supplied keyboard
>   that is presented for UITextField and
>   UITextView objects.

Comment: Thanks santoni, I've thought about using buttons as keys for the  InputView but it seems a bit overkill for a simple task - but it does look like this is the only option for customised keys.

Answer (score 0):

Apple wont allow you to do any alterations to the keyboards..

What do you want to enter? Either create a custom keyboard, use pickers if possible or code it to not accepts certain keys..

Comment: I only want the user to enter numbers and the decimal point, with all other options disabled?

Comment: Okay. I did'nt know you were allowed to change the keyboard now..

I usually use a picker. and have one of the segments just contain a "," the rest of the segments are 0-9..

or you could do something like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276382/best-way-to-enter-numeric-values-with-decimal-points

But since its okay to change the keyboard now try this:

http://blog.devedup.com/index.php/2010/03/13/iphone-number-pad-with-a-decimal-point/

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I did'nt know you were allowed to change the keyboard now..

I usually use a picker. and have one of the segments just contain a "," the rest of the segments are 0-9..

or you could do something like this:

[What is the best way to enter numeric values with decimal points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276382/best-way-to-enter-numeric-values-with-decimal-points)

But since its okay to change the keyboard now try this:

http://blog.devedup.com/index.php/2010/03/13/iphone-number-pad-with-a-decimal-point/

Comment: Both links are great alternatives, but they don't provide the flexibility that I need. I'll definitely keep those options in mind for future projects though. thanks. :)